# Map array into a row of a table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I'm receiving data that looks like this.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "603a651e22",
            "name": "name 1",
            "state": "F",
            "createdAt": "2021-02-25T17:13:42.218Z",
            "participants": [
                {
                    "name": "something",
                    "email": "dasds@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                    "name": "something 2",
                    "email": "dasds@gmail.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "sdfhfh312312",
            "name": "name",
            "state": "F",
            "createdAt": "2021-02-26T18:43:49.240Z",
            "participants": [
                {
                    "name": "something",
                    "email": "dasds@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                    "name": "something 2",
                    "email": "dasds@gmail.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm trying to display it as a table in React 16.9 like this.

```
<Table responsive>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>state</th>
                    <th>created</th>
                    <th>participants</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {data.map((item, index) => {
                      return (
                        <tr key={index}>
                          <th scope="row">{item._id}</th>
                          <td>{item.name}</td>
                          <td>{item.state}</td>
                          <td>{GeneralFunctions.format_all(item.createdAt || '')}</td>
                          <td>{item.participants}</td>
                        </tr>
                      );
                    })}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
```

My problem is that the participants are generally an array of objects and don't get displayed, my question is how could I display or map the array of objects into 1 row of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
 const res = {
    data: [
      {
        _id: "603a651e22",
        name: "name 1",
        state: "F",
        createdAt: "2021-02-25T17:13:42.218Z",
        participants: [
          {
            name: "something",
            email: "dasds@gmail.com",
          },
          {
            name: "something 2",
            email: "dasds@gmail.com",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        _id: "sdfhfh312312",
        name: "name",
        state: "F",
        createdAt: "2021-02-26T18:43:49.240Z",
        participants: [
          {
            name: "something",
            email: "dasds@gmail.com",
          },
          {
            name: "something 2",
            email: "dasds@gmail.com",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
  console.log(res.data);
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>state</th>
            <th>created</th>
            <th>participants</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {res.data?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{item._id}</th>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.state}</td>
                <td>{item.createdAt || ""}</td>
                <td>
                  <ul>
                    {item.participants.map((p, i) => {
                      return (
                        <li key={i}>
                          {p.name} || {p.email}
                        </li>
                      );
                    })}
                  </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

> Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

This mostly depends on how you want to display your participants. A simple example would be:

```
<td>
  <ul>
    {item.participants.map((participant) => (
      <li>{participant.name} ({participant.email})</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</td>
```

Which creates an unordered list for participants and renders each participant into its own list item.